# Error loading QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

Right after uninstalling and re-installing QGIS 3.4.4-2 using OSGEO4W Installer trying to start QGIS 3.4.4 I encounter the following error message:

[image]

My `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin-g7.env` looks like this:

```
PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0\lib;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\msys\bin
GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\gdal
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins
GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
GEOTIFF_CSV=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\epsg_csv
GISBASE=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.6.0
GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\proj
GRASS_PYTHON=C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python.exe
JPEGMEM=1000000
OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGEO4~1
PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\proj
PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\qtplugins;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qt5\plugins
QT_RASTER_CLIP_LIMIT=4096
VSI_CACHE=TRUE
VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
O4W_QT_PREFIX=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5
O4W_QT_BINARIES=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/bin
O4W_QT_PLUGINS=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/plugins
O4W_QT_LIBRARIES=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/lib
O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/translations
O4W_QT_HEADERS=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/Qt5/include
```

The first entry in the `PATH` variable points to the referred `qgis_app.dll`.

The error occurs no matter if I try to start the executable (`qgis-bin-g7.exe`) by double click or from the start menu or the related batchfile (`qgis.bat` or `qgis-grass7.bat`).

Even more confusing: I have installed both `qgis-dev` (3.5) and `qgis` (3.4.4). `qgis-dev` does start even if I double-click the executable (.exe) and `qgis` does NOT start (same error) when double-clicking the batchfiles as mentionend above. No way to make QGIS 3 start.

The `*.env` files and the batchfiles for `qgis` and `qgis-dev` look allmost the same.

What do I miss to make my QGIS 3 running again?!

Comment: You could tr running QGIS as admin?

Comment: tried, but same error :-(

Comment: Having the same exact problem with running QGIS 3.10.0.  I installed it yesterday, ran fine, no problems, tried to run QGIS 3.10.0 today and I get the same exact error message.  The first entry in my PATH variable also points to qgis_app.dll (C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\qgis-bin.env).  Tried running as Administrator, no go.  Restarted PC, no go.  Never happened to me before today.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears if you double click the qgis executable.
Here is the error, in my case, if I try to access directly the executable:
[image]

Try instead to start QGIS double clicking the corresponding batch file (in my case: **qgis-dev-g7.4.0.bat**, like bellow) and everything will be ok.

[image]

Comment: Good hint, but some objections: I have installed both qgis-dev (3.5) and qgis (3.4.4). qgis-dev starts even if I double-click the executable (.exe) and qgis does NOT start (same error) when double-clicking the qgis-grass7.bat (or qgis.bat, respectively). I'll update my question accordingly.